# IE8 Fires 'onChange' for Every Second Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-events

I'm having a problem with a web app at work that essentially works a bit like a spreadsheet.  I have a table with a bunch of text fields to replicate the 'Excel' experience as per the customer's request (Why on earth they can't just USE Excel is beyond me, but it's not my place to say)

I thought I was being super-flashy by having the web app save data as it was entered (That way, users who forget to click 'Save' are well, saved.) This works beautifully in all major browsers thanks to onChange events and AJAX calls (Thanks jQuery!) trouble is, we have to support IE8. Which only seems to be firing an `onChange` event every other time it should be. What this means is that only every second cell is actually saved.

I've done some research but can't find anything to suggest that this is a common thing. So my question is, is IE8 only capable of handling one piece of Javascript at a time? Bearing in mind that because the app behaves like a spreadsheet the users are causing `onChange` events (And therefore AJAX calls) quite rapidly.

Comment: that's why they call it internet exploder!

Comment: you may use the keyup event but then every key stroke will save the cell... maybe using the onblur? when cell loses focus you save it!

Comment: @SparK Wow... Seems inefficient to me, but it worked! (Used onBlur) :-)

Comment: I have a similar setup.   I use `onfocus` to save the element reference and value, then `onblur` I check if the value has changed.  If it has, then I save.  My API lets me save one cell at a time, rather than the whole form. That way, I change the background color of the cells that are being saved and when the ajax results return, I set the color back to normal.  I can also check for unsaved values and warn the user (me!) when I try to leave the screen with uncompleted saves.

Comment: Should I post my comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use the keyup event but then every key stroke will save the cell... maybe using the onblur? when cell loses focus you save it!